# LLVM Pass Linking problem: undefined symbol

Tags: c++, linker, llvm

I'm trying to write my own pass in LLVM but I'm having problems while using my own libraries with it.

Here is how I compile my pass:

```
[shinjitumala@FPRAlienware17M FPR]$ make
[ 000% ] compiling object file obj/fpr/llvm/debug.o...
../../../tools/llvm-project/llvm/build-8.0.1/bin/clang++ -fPIC -Wall -g3 -fno-rtti -MD -o obj/fpr/llvm/debug.o -c src/fpr/llvm/debug.cpp -I../../../tools/llvm-project/llvm/build-8.0.1/../include -I../../../tools/llvm-project/llvm/build-8.0.1/include -Iinclude
[ 025% ] Done!
[ 025% ] compiling object file obj/fpr/out.o...
../../../tools/llvm-project/llvm/build-8.0.1/bin/clang++ -fPIC -Wall -g3 -fno-rtti -MD -o obj/fpr/out.o -c src/fpr/out.cpp -I../../../tools/llvm-project/llvm/build-8.0.1/../include -I../../../tools/llvm-project/llvm/build-8.0.1/include -Iinclude
[ 050% ] Done!
[ 050% ] compiling object file obj/module_pass.o...
../../../tools/llvm-project/llvm/build-8.0.1/bin/clang++ -fPIC -Wall -g3 -fno-rtti -MD -o obj/module_pass.o -c src/module_pass.cpp -I../../../tools/llvm-project/llvm/build-8.0.1/../include -I../../../tools/llvm-project/llvm/build-8.0.1/include -Iinclude
src/module_pass.cpp:24:16: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]
                                for (auto& i : bb) {
                                           ^
src/module_pass.cpp:21:22: warning: unused variable 'context' [-Wunused-variable]
                llvm::LLVMContext& context = m.getContext();
                                   ^
2 warnings generated.
[ 075% ] Done!
[ 075% ] linking binary bin/libFPRPass.so...
../../../tools/llvm-project/llvm/build-8.0.1/bin/clang++ -fPIC -shared -o bin/libFPRPass.so -L../../../tools/llvm-project/llvm/build-8.0.1/lib  obj/fpr/llvm/debug.o  obj/fpr/out.o  obj/module_pass.o
[ 100% ] Done!
[ 100% ] All Done!
```

But here is what I get when I run the pass:

```
[shinjitumala@FPRAlienware17M FPR]$ ../../../tools/llvm-project/llvm/build-8.0.1/bin/opt -load bin/libFPRPass.so -test < main.ll > obj/main_new.ll
../../../tools/llvm-project/llvm/build-8.0.1/bin/opt: symbol lookup error: bin/libFPRPass.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3fpr3outlsIA54_cEERS0_RKT_
```

This does not happen when I simply use my libraries in some test programs. It only happens when I use them inside a LLVM pass.

Here is the code of the pass itself:

```
#include <fpr/out.h>
#include <fpr/llvm/debug.h>

#include <llvm/IR/Module.h>
#include <llvm/Support/CommandLine.h>

static llvm::cl::opt<int> slice_start_line("l");

namespace fpr {
struct ModulePass : public llvm::ModulePass
{
  public:
    static char ID;

    ModulePass()
      : llvm::ModulePass(ID)
    {}

    bool runOnModule(llvm::Module& m) override
    {
        llvm::LLVMContext& context = m.getContext();
        for (auto& f : m) {
            for (auto& bb : f) {
                for (auto& i : bb) {
                    fpr::out(2) << "test\n";
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};
}

/**
 * パスの登録
 */
char fpr::ModulePass::ID = 0;
static llvm::RegisterPass<fpr::ModulePass> module_pass("test", "discription placeholder");
```

I've tried to add/remove the `-shared` flag when linking the program as well as linking it with `--no-undefined` but none of them have worked so far.

I couldn't find exactly what I'm looking for from the old answers either so here am I.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After asking someone smarter than me irl. This was because I had the implementation of `operator<<` in `out.cpp` instead of `out.h`. Which is really silly... It had nothing to do with LLVM.